# Editing and deleting gridview not working after filter

Tags: asp.net

I have a `gridview` where Edit and Delete work fine. But, when I search any record and try to edit that record, the `gridview` is somehow reset to state before filtering.

Here is my code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    Databind();
}
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string TableID=GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    string Name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
    string Dept = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;
    string AttendMonth = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text;
    string AttendYear = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Controls[0]).Text;
    string Month_H = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Controls[0]).Text;
    string Absent_H = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Controls[0]).Text;
    string Miss_punch_H = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9].Controls[0]).Text;
    string Late_H = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10].Controls[0]).Text;
    string Eid_H = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[11].Controls[0]).Text;
    string train_H = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Controls[0]).Text;
    string Manager_H = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[13].Controls[0]).Text;
    string Des_H = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[14].Controls[0]).Text;
    string Percent = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[15].Controls[0]).Text;
    string Notes = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[16].Controls[0]).Text;

    if (DA.UpdateAtten(TableID,Name,Dept,AttendMonth,AttendYear,Month_H,Absent_H,Miss_punch_H,Late_H, Eid_H,train_H,Manager_H,Des_H,Percent,Notes) > 0)
        msg.Text = "updated successfully";
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
   // Databind();
 }
private void Databind()
{
     GridView1.DataSource=DA.GetAllAtten();
     GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

here is the code for this part (DA.UpdateAtten ...etc :

```
public int UpdateAtten(string TableID, string Name, string Dept, string AttendMonth, string AttendYear,string Month_H, string Absent_H, string Miss_punch_H, string Late_H, string Eid_H, string train_H, string Manager_H,string Des_H, string Percent,string Notes)
{
    SqlCommand MyCommnd = new SqlCommand("UpdateAttendanceReport", Myconn);

    MyCommnd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    MyCommnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableID", TableID);
    MyCommnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",Name);
    MyCommnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dept",Dept);
    MyCommnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AttendMonth",AttendMonth);
    MyCommnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AttendYear", AttendYear);
    MyCommnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month_H",Month_H);
    MyCommnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Absent_H",Absent_H);
    MyCommnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Miss_punch_H",Miss_punch_H);
    MyCommnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Late_H", Late_H);
    MyCommnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Eid_H", Eid_H);
    MyCommnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@train_H",train_H);
    MyCommnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manager_H",Manager_H);
    MyCommnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Des_H",Des_H);
    MyCommnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Percent",Percent);
    MyCommnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes",Notes);
    return MyCommnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I amgoing to guess the problem is in your: if (DA.UpdateAtten(TableID,Name,Dept,AttendMonth,AttendYear,Month_H,Absent_H,Miss_punch_H,Late_H, Eid_H,train_H,Manager_H,Des_H,Percent,Notes) > 0)

show that code

Comment: thanks.. i add it :)

Comment: Are you sure that your update method (UpdateAtten) is in fact executing succeesfully? (Are you opening your connection Myconn somewhere else?).
Put break points in your code to see what values are being returned.

Comment: I solved it by re-applying the search and it works perfect now..thank you

Comment: were my comments helpful? If so, glad they were.
 can you elaborate: "re-applying search" ?

Comment: It's not on the method (UpdateAtten), I re-applied the filter before RowEditing method ends like this:
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    Databind();
    SearchButton_Click(sender,e)
}